Get element by ID and change its color in SVG Inkscape
I have a simple drawing I created using Inkscape, this is the Inkscape file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="847.18634"
   height="635.83612"
   viewBox="0 0 224.15139 168.23164"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   inkscape:version="1.3.2 (1:1.3.2+202311252150+091e20ef0f)"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing.svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <script
     xlink:href="script.js"
     id="script2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="false"
     inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     showgrid="false"
     showborder="true"
     shape-rendering="auto"
     inkscape:zoom="0.69947917"
     inkscape:cx="711.24348"
     inkscape:cy="274.48995"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1054"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="0"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-66.199001,-70.460732)">
    <circle
       style="fill:#ff0000;stroke-width:1;stroke-linejoin:round;paint-order:markers fill stroke"
       id="circle"
       cx="97.842422"
       cy="117.80233"
       r="31.643421" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#ff0000;stroke-width:1;stroke-linejoin:round;paint-order:markers fill stroke"
       id="square"
       width="58.322342"
       height="58.322342"
       x="197.28148"
       y="70.460732" />
    <path
       sodipodi:type="star"
       style="fill:#ff0000;stroke-width:1;stroke-linejoin:round;paint-order:markers fill stroke"
       id="star"
       inkscape:flatsided="false"
       sodipodi:sides="7"
       sodipodi:cx="246.21613"
       sodipodi:cy="196.8262"
       sodipodi:r1="44.441872"
       sodipodi:r2="23.465311"
       sodipodi:arg1="-1.6774691"
       sodipodi:arg2="-1.2286702"
       inkscape:rounded="-3.469447e-18"
       inkscape:randomized="0"
       d="m 241.48437,152.63694 12.60415,22.08392 23.72596,-9.14564 -9.40734,23.62341 21.94324,12.84749 -24.33491,7.374 3.63682,25.1662 -20.9378,-14.42819 -17.4082,18.53425 -1.7741,-25.36566 -25.34449,-2.05437 18.72554,-17.20226 -14.19587,-21.09601 25.12446,3.91478 z"
       inkscape:transform-center-x="2.9669026"
       inkscape:transform-center-y="-4.1349791" />
  </g>
</svg>

and looks like this:

I want to do things with those elements using a JavaScript script, similarly as you would do in an HTML file. I created the following script:
console.log("I am alive!");

var circle = document.getElementById('circle');
circle.style.fill = "#0000ff"; // Make it blue.

console.log(circle);

and embedded it in the SVG file using Inkscape→File→Document properties→Scripting→External scripts→my_script.js. It prints I am alive! but then circle is null. Inspired by this link I also tried
console.log("I am alive!");

console.log(svgDocument.getElementById("circle"));

which prints Uncaught ReferenceError: svgDocument is not defined. Following this link I tried
console.log("I am alive!");

var svgObject = document.getElementById('svg-object').contentDocument;
var element = svgObject.getElementById('circle');

console.log(element);

and
console.log("I am alive!");

var svgObject = document.getElementById('svg5').contentDocument;
var element = svgObject.getElementById('circle');

console.log(element);

and
console.log("I am alive!");

var svgObject = document.getElementById('svg5');
var element = svgObject.getElementById('circle');

console.log(element);

but they all fail.
What is the way of writing this JavaScript such that when I open the SVG with a web browser this works?

The script is appended at the top/start of the document. If you move it to the bottom of the document you can select the circle. You could also wrap your function a a event listener like DOMContentLoaded to ensure the script runs after the svg DOM is parsed.

Wow, yes, it was as simple as that! You can promote your comment to an answer.

And postprocess your (inkscape) SVG file with https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ to get rid of all non-web data in that SVG file.

Make sure that you wait for the DOM to load. I inserted the following script as an embedded script in Inkscape:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.getElementById('path1').style.fill = 'blue';
});

And got the following result, saving the document as a plain SVG document:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="200"
   height="200"
   viewBox="0 0 200 200"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <script
     id="script1">document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e =&gt; {
  document.getElementById('path1').style.fill = 'blue';
});</script>
  <defs
     id="defs1" />
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <path
       style="fill:#ff0000;stroke-width:14.844;stroke-linecap:round"
       id="path1"
       d="M 90.234723,183.97224 A 82.22879,83.852211 0 0 1 11.095695,100.59093 82.22879,83.852211 0 0 1 89.427955,16.421145 82.22879,83.852211 0 0 1 175.22041,92.6532 82.22879,83.852211 0 0 1 104.17524,183.29802" />
  </g>
</svg>



For some reason Inkscape is not escaping the JavaScript code in a CDATA element, but only escaping characters like the > that becomes &gt;. In my book a proper script element containing JavaScript in a SVG document would look like this:
<script>
  //<![CDATA[
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
      document.getElementById('path1').style.fill = 'blue';
    });
  //]]>
</script>

